# How to create a copy of UIView objects, and decrease the font size of a particular label, where views are made programmatically, in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

I have created views programmatically on sub views.

```
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(30, cgfloat  , 270, 120))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 40.0


    let Attdate: UILabel = UILabel()
    Attdate.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 100, 25)
    Attdate.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    Attdate.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    Attdate.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeue", size: 106)
    Attdate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    Attdate.text = AttDate.description
    view1.addSubview(Attdate)
```

I have an array as a response string from server which gives me an array of data. And I want to print that data into the labels. The labels should get called dynamically as the per the array length. And thats THE reason, I am trying to duplicate view1(my UIView object). I tried nskeyedarchiver(not sure how it will help).

```
extension UIView{
     {
     func copyView() -> AnyObject
     {
        return          NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self))!
     }
     }
```

And declared:

```
    let view1 = UIView()
    let copiedView = view1.copyView() as! UIView
    print("CopiedView:\(copiedView)")
```

But, no luck :(
Also, I tried many syntaxes to decrease the font size of a particular label, but none seemed to work.

Kindly reply.

Comment: Hello. You need to make your own class, `CustomView`, subclass of `UIView`. In `CustomView` you will able to perform all behavior what you need. You will be able also to write initializer for make creating objects of `CustomView` very simple, `let customView = CustomView()` for example. Read more Apple documentation about class system for more info

Comment: Thank-you for your reply. Sir, I have already created a class and initialised everything. Please let me know how to create a copy of view1 and decrease the size of a particular label.

Comment: To create an instance of your class just do: `var instance = CustomView()`

Answer (score 1):

To decrease the font size of a particular label, there are two options:

1. You can make the font size part of an initializer, so you can set it every time you have to create one, like this:

.

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    init(fontSizeOfLabel : CGFloat) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 20, width: 270, height: 120))
        // all your normal code in here

         let Attdate: UILabel = UILabel()
         Attdate.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeue", size: fontSizeOfLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

1. Or you can loop over its subviews and change it **after** you have created it:

.

```
var instance = CustomView()
for subview in instance.subviews {
    if var label = subview as? UILabel { //check if it can convert the subview into a UILabel, if it can it is your label
        label.font = UIFont(name: "BebasNeue", size: 70)
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the second solution, I have checked the first one

Comment: Sir, why do I have to make a new class to decrease the font size of a label? Is there any simpler way out to reinitialise the UIView objects?

Comment: Sir, I created a child class and called it in VviewDidLoad class and below is the code:                                                                                                                             override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //setArray()
        let instance = CustomView(fontSizeOfLabel: 12)
       
        
        att_ver_stack_view.addSubview(instance)        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

Comment: You don't have to create a new class for that, that code was just to show you how to use the initializer in the custom class you already had.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it did not worked. Is there any other way out to this? let me know..